# Create TEMPORARY table using Insert Openrowset from .csv file with XML Bulk format file

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, csv, bulkinsert

Microsoft's Tech Page says you can do the following to import from a .csv file into a physical sample table using a format file. I have that working.

> **Using the OPENROWSET Bulk Rowset Provider**
>
> The following example uses INSERT ... SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...) to bulk import data
> from the myTestFormatFiles-c.Dat data file into
> HumanResources.myTestFormatFiles table in the AdventureWorks sample
> database. This example uses an XML format file, MyTestFormatFiles.Xml.
> The example deletes any existing table rows before importing the data
> file. In SQL Server Management Studio Query Editor, execute:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
DELETE myTestFormatFiles;
GO
INSERT INTO myTestFormatFiles
    SELECT *
      FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'C:\myTestFormatFiles-c.Dat',
      FORMATFILE='C:\myTestFormatFiles.Xml'     
      ) as t1 ;
GO
SELECT * FROM myTestFormatFiles;
GO
-- When you finish using the sample table, you can drop it using the following statement:
DROP TABLE myTestFormatFiles
```

However, I want to do exactly this but importing into a **temporary** #table that does not yet exist (similar to the way one can create a new table with a select into statement). Is that possible, and if not, why not?

Adjunct Question: Can you use select into to create a temporary table?
I know that you can use [select into to create a table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).

Now can I use import bulk OPENROWSET with a not yet existing temporary table to create the table and import into it:

```
   INSERT INTO #TestFormatFiles
        SELECT *
          FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'C:\myTestFormatFiles-c.Dat',
          FORMATFILE='C:\myTestFormatFiles.Xml'     
          ) as t1 ;
    GO
```

Testing tells me no: `Invalid Object name #TestFormatFiles`

But is there a way without having to create the temp table from an existing table?

Comment: Do you know the structure of the data you are inserting in advance or will it vary?

Comment: Don't have time to try now, but have you tried the normal way how temp. tables are created, `select * into #tmp from...`

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Instead use `SELECT * INTO #TestFormatFiles FROM OPENROWSET...`.

(You almost had it: You just can't `INSERT INTO` a table that doesn't exist.)